# Division hide in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have different divisions with hide/show tag.  What I need is the following: If one division is opened, other divisions should be hided. The jQuery used in this code: **jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js** and the complete code is given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.bhlink').on('click', function () {
        $(this).text(function (i, txt) {
            return txt.indexOf('MORE') != -1 ? 'HIDE' : 'MORE';
        }).closest('.nn').next('.bhinfo').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.bhinfo {  display: none; }
.nn { margin: 5px 0 5px 0; font-weight: bold;}
```

**HTML in body:**

```
David jhon<br /><div class="nn">
<a class="bhlink" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a></div>
<div class="bhinfo">Mobile: 99934 59234</div>  

Peter mick <br /><div class="nn">
<a class="bhlink" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a></div>
<div class="bhinfo">Mobile: 88934 59234</div>

Sleek boon <br /><div class="nn">
<a class="bhlink" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a></div>
<div class="bhinfo">Mobile: 76534 59234</div>
```

Kindly help me out, in correcting the code please?

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` will wrap a **single** element, there's no need to pass a function into `text`, as you know it will only loop over one element.

You're also not, as far as I can tell, actually making any effort to show or hide anything.

I assume clicking a HIDE link should hide its associated div. So *(see code comments)*:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.bhlink').on('click', function () {
        // Get jQuery wrappers for the link that was clicked,
        // and the .bhinfo connected to it
        var $this = $(this),
            $bhinfo = $this.closest(".nn").next(".bhinfo");

        // Are we showing or hiding?
        if ($this.text() == 'MORE') {
            // Showing, hide all that are visible and change
            // their links' associated text to 'MORE'
            $(".bhinfo:visible")
              .slideUp()
              .prev(".nn").find(".bhlink").text('MORE');
            // Show our div and change our text
            $bhinfo.slideDown();
            $this.text('HIDE');
        } else {
            // Hiding -- just slide our div up and change our text
            $bhinfo.slideUp();
            $this.text('MORE');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.bhinfo {  display: none; }
.nn { margin: 5px 0 5px 0; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
David jhon<br /><div class="nn">
<a class="bhlink" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a></div>
<div class="bhinfo">Mobile: 99934 59234</div>  

Peter mick <br /><div class="nn">
<a class="bhlink" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a></div>
<div class="bhinfo">Mobile: 88934 59234</div>

Sleek boon <br /><div class="nn">
<a class="bhlink" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a></div>
<div class="bhinfo">Mobile: 76534 59234</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is not working, if we put in table ( in two rows)

Comment: @guruje: Well, that wasn't the question you asked. I answered the question you asked. Of course code that uses `closest` and `next` and such is going to be sensitive to the DOM structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** to get other divs

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.bhlink').on('click', function() {
    $(this).text(function(i, txt) {
        return txt.indexOf('MORE') != -1 ? 'HIDE' : 'MORE';
      }).closest('.nn')
      .next('.bhinfo')
      .slideToggle()
      //For getting sibling div to hide them
      .siblings('.bhinfo').slideUp()
      //For Changing their text from HIDE to MORE
      .prev('.nn').find('a').text('MORE');
  });
});
```

```css
.bhinfo {
  display: none;
}
.nn {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
HTML in body:
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
David jhon
<br />
<div class="nn">
  <a class="bhlink" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a>
</div>
<div class="bhinfo">Mobile: 99934 59234</div>

Peter mick
<br />
<div class="nn">
  <a class="bhlink" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a>
</div>
<div class="bhinfo">Mobile: 88934 59234</div>

Sleek boon
<br />
<div class="nn">
  <a class="bhlink" href="javascript:void(0)">MORE</a>
</div>
<div class="bhinfo">Mobile: 76534 59234</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use below code.  `$('.bhinfo').slideUp();` and `$('.bhlink').text('MORE');`

`slideUp()` is apply to all `bhinfo` element.

`$('.bhlink').text('MORE');`  change text to `MORE` in all `bhlink` element.

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/6vqp1ker/1/)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.bhlink').on('click', function () {
    $('.bhinfo').slideUp();   // add this code
    $('.bhlink').text('MORE');  // add this code
    $(this).text(function (i, txt) {
        return txt.indexOf('MORE') != -1 ? 'HIDE' : 'MORE';
    }).closest('.nn').next('.bhinfo').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: provide reason for down vote .. whats wrong in code ?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.bhlink').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent('.nn').find('.bhinfo').slideToggle();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

hope this script helps. please try and let me know.